# PHP/MySQL/PDO - MySQL-Update-Statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

hope you can help me with this problem:

Then I am trying to update my MySQL-Database it doesn't work. If I try to select all data or insert some data it works. If you need any more data/code, just say, i hope I can give that informations.

**File 1 (SQL-Connection etc.)**

```
protected $dbh;
protected $dbh;

public function __construct() {
$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}

public function query($query) {
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function execute() {
$this->stmt->execute();
]
```

**File 2 (insert, select, update SQL)**

```
$this->query("UPDATE BranchOffices SET name = 'TEST' WHERE idBranchOffice = 3");
$this->execute;
```

Also tested with follow SQL-Statements:

```
UPDATE BranchOffices SET name='TEST' WHERE idBranchOffice='3'
UPDATE 'BranchOffices' SET 'name'='TEST' WHERE 'idBranchOffice'=3
UPDATE 'BranchOffices' SET 'name'='TEST' WHERE 'idBranchOffice'='3'
```

**Database Table BranchOffices**

```
column idBranchOffice
column name

data:
1, Test
2, TestTwo
3, TestThree
```

**Output of print_r($this) in File 2**

```
branchOfficeModel Object ( [dbh:protected] => PDO Object ( ) [stmt:protected] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => UPDATE BranchOffices SET name = 'TEST' WHERE idBranchOffice = 3 ) )
```

Hope you have any ideas.
User is root with enought rights.

regards

Markus

Comment: misstype or you really do "$this->execute" without () ?

Comment: pdo does not allow quoted string in sql statements by default. Try replace 'TEST' to named parameter or question mark and bind the parameter to the string value you want.

Comment: In **File2**, change `$this->execute;` to `$this->execute();`

Comment: @MacBooc
Oh man! Thank you! Was sitting days and hours to find the problem!
IT WORKS!